# MySQL table is broken after failed dump process using mysqldump

Tags: mysql

I need to dump MySQL InnoDB-database consists of several tables. One table that causes problems has nearly 13 Million rows. A fresh install of XAMPP(V.3.2.2) dump process was successful, after that,  dump process always failed with the error message "mysqldump: Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when dumping table `gv_faktur_header_history` at row: 2623629". At this point here's the status :

- Can not insert any value (Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL)
- Can not issue "CHECK TABLE" command (Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL)
- Can not alter this table (add column)
- Can select data from this table
- Can select row 2623629 (select * from table limit 2623629 ,1)
- Can run "show table status" command

I repeat this process several times like this :

1. Reinstalling xampp
2. Importing database using this method

```
> set global net_buffer_length = 1000000; 
> set global max_allowed_packet = 1000000000; 
> SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
> SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 0; 
> SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0; 
> use db_name; 
> source backup-file.sql SET
> foreign_key_checks = 1; 
> SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 1; 
> SET AUTOCOMMIT = 1;
```

3. Dump the database w/o --skip-extending-insert (success)
4. Dump the database w/o --skip-extending-insert (failed)
5. Dump the database w/o --skip-extending-insert (failed)

mysqldump command :

```
mysqldump -u root -p --skip-extended-insert --max-allowed-packet=1G --net-buffer-length=32704 rent_scaff header_history > D:\dobol
```

Environment specifications :

- i5 8 gen
- Ram 8 GB (3 Gb unuse as seen in task manager)
- SSD Storage 512G
- mysqldump  Ver 10.16 Distrib 10.1.10-MariaDB

here's my.ini configuration

```
[client] 
# password       = your_password 
port            = 3306 
socket          = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"

[mysqld]
port= 3306
socket = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir = "C:/xampp/mysql" 
tmpdir = "C:/xampp/tmp" 
datadir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file = "mysql.pid"
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1G
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
log_error = "mysql_error.log"
plugin_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/lib/plugin/" 
server-id   = 1
innodb_data_home_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
innodb_log_file_size = 250M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 250M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 1G

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
enter code here
```

Mysql Log :

```
Server version: 10.1.10-MariaDB
key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=262144
max_used_connections=2
max_threads=1001
thread_count=2
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 787099 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0x3eee2178
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
mysqld.exe!my_parameter_handler()
mysqld.exe!my_mb_ctype_mb()
mysqld.exe!??2Geometry@@SAPAXIPAX@Z()
mysqld.exe!??2Geometry@@SAPAXIPAX@Z()
mysqld.exe!?propagate_equal_fields@Item_func_expr_str_metadata@@UAEPAVItem@@PAVTHD@@ABVContext@Value_source@@PAVCOND_EQUAL@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!??2Geometry@@SAPAXIPAX@Z()
mysqld.exe!??2Geometry@@SAPAXIPAX@Z()
mysqld.exe!??2Geometry@@SAPAXIPAX@Z()
mysqld.exe!??0Alter_table_prelocking_strategy@@QAE@XZ()
mysqld.exe!?mysql_alter_table@@YA_NPAVTHD@@PAD1PAUHA_CREATE_INFO@@PAUTABLE_LIST@@PAVAlter_info@@IPAUst_order@@_N@Z()
mysqld.exe!?execute@Sql_cmd_alter_table@@UAE_NPAVTHD@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?mysql_execute_command@@YAHPAVTHD@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?mysql_parse@@YAXPAVTHD@@PADIPAVParser_state@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?dispatch_command@@YA_NW4enum_server_command@@PAVTHD@@PADI@Z()
mysqld.exe!?do_command@@YA_NPAVTHD@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?threadpool_process_request@@YAHPAVTHD@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?tp_end@@YAXXZ()
KERNEL32.DLL!SetUserGeoName()
ntdll.dll!TpCheckTerminateWorker()
ntdll.dll!TpCallbackIndependent()
KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
ntdll.dll!RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath()
ntdll.dll!RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath()

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
```

Please help me how to Dump (backup) a large database, at least how to safely dump the database, so when the process failed, the table remains usable.

Comment: This is off-topic and should be on [Database Admin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) :)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I'll post to [Database Admin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: No problem ! It's normal to don't know all of those community x)

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that either one command is taking forever and it timing out, or that there is too much data to fit in the cache at one time.

I would try using a program, something like HeidiSQL, to do the backup of the database. This would allow the backup to be in stages instead of one giant request.

This would be the example to do this with HeidiSQL. Feel free to replace 127.0.0.1 with a different IP address if the SQL server is on a second computer, or any other setting that you think is different.

You would start by setting up the connection:
[HeidiSQL Sesssion Manager Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xk2We.png)

- Then, click on OPEN
- Right click on your database, located in the top left of the screen
- Click EXPORT DATABASE AS SQL

First we'll backup the structure of your database:

- Click the checkbox on the left side
- Click on SQL export on the right-side tab

  - Database -> Drop (unchecked), Create (checked)
  - Table -> Drop (unchecked), Create (checked)
  - Data -> No Data
  - Output -> Single .sql file
  - Filename -> Click the folder icon, pick a location and name the file something like DB_Structure.sql
- Finally, click Export

Next, we will backup the data from the database:

-Same steps as before, in SQL Export do:

- Database -> Drop (uncheck), Create (uncheck)
- Table -> Drop (uncheck), Create (uncheck)
- Data -> Change from No Data to Insert
- Max INSERT Size -> 1024
- Output -> Change from Single .sql file to ZIP compressed .sql file
- Filename -> Click the folder icon, Pick a location and name the file something like DB_Data.zip
- Finally, click Export

This is how you would Use those backup files:

- Click on the tab named ►Query
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>
- In the Open File dialog box, navigate to your backup SQL file for the structure
- Then click Open
- Next, press <kbd>F9</kbd> to run the SQL commands

When this is finished, you do the same process for the data SQL backup file.

Comment: Hi Ivar Harris, thank you for your reply. It's not a time-out problem, as I wrote in the post, for the fresh install of xampp, the dump process is successful (5 minutes), after the first dump, the second dump only lasts about 30 seconds and failed. Thank you for informing me HeidiSQL, I Would try that out, but I'm still curious about my problem